# How to compare a pixel with its surounding as fast as possible?

Tags: python, algorithm, image, image-processing

I am trying to find a fast algorithm such as :

- input: `Image (width w x height h)`, `radius R`
- content: for each pixel (x,y) as

  - x in [R, w-R]
  - y in [R, h-R]

  find the most represented color in the circle of radius `R` and center (x,y). (In the image)
- output: `Image (w-2R x h-2R)` the image built from the results

I have, for now, implemented the base algorithm of that in python, that has a complexity `O(n*R^2)` (with `n = w*h`).

I'm now wondering if an algorithm of complexity `O(n)` may exist. It sounds possible to me, but I cannot manage to build one.

So:

- **Do you think a such algorithm may exist ?**

  - If so, what would he use / how would he work ?
  - Otherwise, why ?
- **How can I speed up the execution of my algorithm ?** (in an algorithm way, i.e. regardless of parallelization)

**Edits**:

- I use an image representation with a 2 dimensions array. Each pixel (i.e. cell of the array) is a tuple of ints: Red, Green, Blue, between 0 and 255.
- Before running this algorithm, I "level" the image: reduce the number of different colors present in the image (by a kind of *clustering* on color and proximity)
- If every pixel is different in the surrounding, then it should remain with the same color (for now implemented by giving a "weight" more important to the original pixel's color)

*Note: I am not sure that "comparing a pixel with its surrounding" is the best way to describe what I want to do, so if you have ideas to improve the title, let me know in the comments*

Comment: not sure but you need `n` already because you definitely need to go over the whole image, but you also need to check if the particular pixel is in the radius which makes for two checks, so I can't exactly imagine an algorithm that would be `O(n)`

Comment: I can imagine a way in which each pixel, when visited, kind of "propagate" its information so that the next pixels do not need to actually check its value (a bit like in that backpack problem). But I don't manage to build in my head something that may work.

Comment: How exactly are you representing the image? Have you considered looking for image-specific tools for this sort of task?

Comment: "I have, for now, implemented the base algorithm of that in python, that has a complexity O(n*R^2) (with n = w*h). I'm now wondering if an algorithm of complexity O(n) may exist." Assuming `R` is a constant value, *these are the same thing*. If you want the code not to take any longer as `R` increases, you are out of luck; as `R` increases, there are more pixels inside the circle, and clearly you cannot exactly answer the question without considering every pixel in the circle. You could, of course, take a *random sampling of* those pixels, taking a hint from statistics.

Comment: *How exactly are you representing the image?*
As an 2D array of colors (tuples of 3 ints). ___
*Have you considered looking for image-specific tools for this sort of task?*
I'm not sure to understand, what do you mean by "image-specific tools"? 
___
And yes it sounds normal that complexity increase with `R`. But I feel like it's possible to be more efficient, because for two pixels side-by-side we're almost computing the same area. But I may be wrong.

Comment: What is “the most represented color”? Is this the mode? What if each pixel in the circle has a unique color?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I'll make this more clear in the post

Comment: You can calculate the mean in fewer than O(R^2) per pixel. For the median this is possible too, but only for 8-bit or 16-bit grayscale images (and it’s only efficient for larger R).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Do you have any links with more explanations about that ?

Comment: None off the top of my head, sorry. For circular filters, you typically decompose them into lines. For the mean filter, as you move the circle over one pixel, you have one pixel exiting each line, and one pixel entering. So you update the mean over the circle by subtracting the values exiting on the left, and adding the values entering on the right. (1/2)

Comment: A median filter can be optimized by putting all values under the kernel in a histogram; as you move the kernel, you update the histogram in the same way as you do the mean, removing and adding values to the histogram. You could probably do something similar in your case. I would suggest you apply your filter to an image where each pixel is the cluster ID, rather than the color associated to that cluster. It will make everything else that much easier. (2/2)

Comment: Thank you for those clues. I'll try to improve my algorithm and get back here if I manage to do something better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on *Cris Luengo* comments, I improved my algorithm by:

- Replacing data structure's content from tuples of int to ids of clusters
- Using a "moving kernel": from pixel (x,y) to (x+1, y), only updating the content about the cells leaving and entering the kernel

  - This improvement is more visible as the radius `R` grows

So, input: `image`, `radius`

1. Replace colors by ids

   ```py
   colors = {}
   id_counter = 0
   raw = np.zeros((image.width, image.height))
   data = image.load()
   for x in range(image.width):
       for y in range(image.height):
           color = data[x,y]
           id = colors.get(color, -1)
           if id == -1:
               id = id_counter
               id_counter += 1
               colors[color] = id
           raw[x,y] = id
   ```
2. Build `kernel` and `delta kernel`. Delta kernel contains the relative positions of cells leaving and entering, and if they are leaving or entering

   ```py
   kernel = []
   for dx in range(-radius, radius+1):
       for dy in range(-radius, radius+1):
           if dx*dx + dy*dy <= radius*radius:
               kernel.append((dx,dy))

   delta_kernel = []
   for dx in range(-radius, radius+1):
       mini = None
       for dy in range(-radius, radius+1):
           if dx*dx + dy*dy <= radius*radius:
               mini = dy - 1
               break
       delta_kernel.append((dx, mini, -1))

   for dx in range(-radius, radius+1):
       maxi = -9999
       for dy in range(-radius, radius+1):
           if dx*dx + dy*dy <= radius*radius:
               maxi = max(dy, maxi)
       delta_kernel .append((dx, maxi, 1))
   ```

   *Note: this is actually merged in one loop, but for sake of clarity, I separated the steps*
3. Actual algorithm

   ```py
   counter = {} # Map counting occurrences
   new_raw = np.zeros((raw.shape[0] - radius*2, raw.shape[1] - radius*2))

   direction = +1 # Y direction +/-1
   y = radius
   for x in range(radius, raw.shape[0]-radius):
       if x == radius: # First time: full kernel
           for (dx, dy) in kernel:
               key = raw[x+dx, y+dy]
               counter[key] = counter.get(key, 0) + 1
       else: # move to the right (x++): delta kernel horizontally
           for (dy, dx, sign) in delta_kernel:
               key = raw[x + dx, y + direction*dy]
               new_val = counter.get(key,0) + sign
               if new_val <= 0:
                   counter.pop(key) # Remove key to useless key values in the map
               else:
                   counter[key] = new_val

       for i in range(raw.shape[1]-2*radius):
           if i > 0:
               # y moves forward: delta radius (on y=0, x moved forward not y)
               for (dx, dy, sign) in delta_kernel:
                   key = raw[x + dx, y + direction*dy]
                   new_val = counter.get(key,0) + sign
                   if new_val <= 0:
                       counter.pop(key)
                   else:
                       counter[key] = new_val

           # Find most represented value
           winner_item = max(counter.items(), key=lambda i:i[1])
           if winner_item[1] == 1: # Every pixels are different: take the center one by default.
               winner_key = raw[x,y]
           else:
               winner_key = winner_item[0]
           new_raw[x-radius, y-radius] = winner_key
           y += direction
       y -= direction # Prevent y to go out from range

       direction *= -1
   ```
4. Rebuild an image

   ```py
   reversed_color_map = {}
   for key, value in colors.items():
       reversed_color_map[value] = key

   result = Image.new(mode=image.mode, size=(image.width-2*radius, image.height-2*radius))
   out_data = result.load()
   for x in range(raw.shape[0]):
       for y in range(raw.shape[1]):
           out_data[x,y] = reversed_color_map[raw[x,y]]
   ```

Comments, remarks, ideas for improvement are welcome :)